# What hooks do I need to hook into to capture ever wp_user creation/change?

Tags: hooks, users, user-registration

I have a wordpress site and I have an external database I need to keep updated with the user information.

Whenever a user is created, updated, or otherwise modified by something like an admin, I need to update the other database. I thought there would be one or two hooks I would need to hook into (user created + user updated), but now I see that there are more than just those two.

```
user_register
profile_update
edit_user_profile_update
```

Are there any that I am missing? Which hooks do I need to get the job done? Does anyone have any advice to code this up?

URLs:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those first 2 actions you linked to from the codex, `user_register` and `profile_update` should be exactly what you need.

`user_register` runs right after a user has successfully registered and gives you access to their $user_id which you can use to retrieve any user data you need, like name, email, etc.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wse_custom_register_action', 10, 1 );
function wse_custom_register_action( $user_id ) {
    // send data to your external db/API
}
```

`profile_update` works exactly the same way, and gives you access to both the old user data and the new, updated user data.

I don't believe you would need `edit_user_profile_update` in this instance.